# Define variable in Jinja template

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have  this loop

```
{% for node in groups['PROXY'] %}
{% if ansible_default_ipv4 != hostvars[node].ansible_ssh_host %}
  {{ hostvars[node].ansible_ssh_host }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

very simple, my question is, how can I change this

```
groups['PROXY']
```

in a variable that I could define in my vars/main.yml?

Comment: @Carmine you just define your variable in vars/main.yml and use it, no big deal

Comment: @WojciechKaczmarek It doesn't work, I tried, if I will define a variable like this:      `group: groups['PROXY'] ` and then    `{% for node in group %}` , it doesn't read it I am getting `"AnsibleUndefinedVariable: u\"hostvars['g']\" is undefined"`

Comment: (1) You should include this information in the question when you posted. As of now the question is unclear and should be closed. (2) You defined a string `groups['PROXY']` and iterate over it. First element is `g`. As such host does not exist, you get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `group: "{{ groups['PROXY'] }}"`

This will tell ansible to store the value of the variable groups (because of the the brackets), as opposed to a string (without the brackets)